# Using Visual Studio Comm 2019 to create BI Cube. Wizard welcome screens won't go away, so can't enter information

Tags: visual-studio, cube

Using Visual Studio Community Edition 2019 to create BI Cube.  Just installed that latest Microsoft.DataTools.AnalysisServices add on.  The Wizards for both adding a Data Source and for adding a Data Source View both start with a welcome screen that occludes the input fields and they won't go away, so I can't enter information. They both have a check box that says "don't show again", but that does not help, they continue to show, even after I click thru taking all the defaults, save the project, and restart it.

See image.

[image: Wizard welcome that won't go away]

Answer (score 0):

MS actaully got back to me quickly, on a Sunday!  thank you Patrick.

"One thing we’ve noticed is that for VS 2019, sometimes you can get a better experience by following this trick:
“Navigate to Tools in the Menu bar, then click ‘Options’. Next, under the Environment tab click ‘General’ and uncheck the option 'Optimize rendering for screens with different pixel densities'.”
 
That disables a newer PMA (Per-Monitor-Awareness) feature of Visual Studio that our extension hasn’t yet been updated to take account of.